# How to assess the visibility of the roofs from given locations in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am trying to assess if the roofs of the buildings are seen from given locations (observers "points" on the street). The observer's angle is 45 degrees (see attachment). I have only the buildings layer as a multipatch and the points layer.
[image]

I have tried Skyline and Visibility tools on ArcGIS Pro but I did not get the needed results.

Comment: The usual definition of "visibility" is not so constricted. It seems as if you will have to do a lot of math on your own, perhaps using gaming raytracing software, and not GIS applications.

Answer (score 1):

[Convert multipatch to raster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/multipatch-to-raster.htm).  Use the resulting raster, and the point, with [visibility](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/visibility.htm) to determine those areas that are visible given your angle requirements.
You will need a 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst toolbox to have access to visibility tools.